# Add to cart product with custom option "file"

Tags: custom-options, magento2.4, file-upload

I am trying to add products to cart with custom options. All are working but if custom options is **file**, it's not working. I've tried everything so far, but no luck. Anyone tried this and have a solution? TIA!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I figured it out, Pls comment if I'm doing wrong,

For M2 (Magento2.4.2), the following worked for me:
Suppose your form file upload html looks like below : (Loaded with core function)

```
<div class="control" id="input-box-options_22_file">
        <input type="file" name="options_22_file" id="options_22_file" class="product-custom-option required" aria-required="true">
        <input type="hidden" name="options_22_file_action" value="save_new" aria-required="true">
</div>
```

Then on your form submit you need an ajax request as well since Magento send binary of the file with params, but if you send it without ajax, probably only file name will be passed. To do ajax:

```
$('#addCart').on('submit',(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
         url: config.addCartUrl,
    type: "POST",
    data:  new FormData(this),
    contentType: false,
         cache: false,
    processData:false,
    });
        
    }));
```

In your addToCart.php you can traverse the options and if found with file you can do following:

```
foreach ($product->getOptions() as $o)
      {
       foreach ($o->getValues() as $value)
              {
                  //do traversing for other option types
               }   
       if($o->getType() == "file")
            {
              $params['options_'.$o->getOptionId().'_file_action'] = 
              $postParams['options_'.$o->getOptionId().'_file_action'];
            }
               //$postParams is params from form submitted
     }
       $this->cart->addProduct($product, $params);
//don't forget to append other required params for add to cart
```

This will add to cart products with custom option type "file" without issues hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

for this version 2.4.2 there is a reported [bug](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/32121), you should apply a patch with [this fix](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/9ce80c9914b740d30aef5cef7bbca8febe64a0c5) I tested and it works now after applying the diff